Exist Form Call as New Form Edit Option Not Working in VB.Net
I have Created the 3 Forms as below i have adding the data in DG_Frm DataGridView when was need to edit the particluar data to click the edit column of DataGridview showdialog as Edit_Frm after   editing click the button should be updat in DG_Frm DataGridView.
But This Not working.
if i have removed call of Dim data_frm As New DG_Frm() from Form1 it's working.
How to fix this issue...
1st Form
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Me.Panel1.Controls.Clear()

        Dim data_frm As New DG_Frm()
        data_frm.TopLevel = False
        data_frm.TopMost = True
        data_frm.Height = Me.Panel1.Height - 50
        data_frm.Width = Me.Panel1.Width - 10
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(data_frm)
        data_frm.Show()

    End Sub


End Class

2nd Form
Public Class DG_Frm
    Private Sub DG_Frm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub DGItems_RowPrePaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles DGItems.RowPrePaint
        '''''''''''''''' Auto Sl No Update in Data GridView
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            Me.DGItems.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = e.RowIndex + 1
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim name As String
        name = Me.TextBox1.Text

        DGItems.Rows.Add("", name)

    End Sub

    Private Sub DGItems_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGItems.CellContentClick

        Dim colname As String = DGItems.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name

        If colname = "clmEdit" Then

            Dim Edit_Frm As New Edit_Frm

            Edit_Frm.TextBox1.Text = DGItems.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString
            Edit_Frm.TextBox2.Text = DGItems.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value.ToString
            Edit_Frm.ShowDialog()
        End If

    End Sub

End Class

3rd Form
Public Class Edit_Frm
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim rowno As String
        rowno = Me.TextBox1.Text
        For i = 0 To DG_Frm.DGItems.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim name As String
            name = Me.TextBox2.Text
            If i = rowno Then
                DG_Frm.DGItems.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = name
            End If
        Next
        Me.Close()

    End Sub

End Class

```

